# Problems grabbing file names using SDL_strdup and similar

Tags: c, malloc, sdl-2, opendir, strdup

I'm trying to create a program with SDL2.
In a certain part of the code, I'm writing functions to grab names of all present files in a given directory path (and keep them in memory) so that, in another function, I can check if a specified file was present the last moment the directory was checked.
I'm using `dirent.h` to suit my needs but I'm running into a few problems:

1. All the files are properly captured by `readdir()` (no exception), however they aren't *always* properly copied into memory after using `SDL_strdup()` (code is below).
2. I'm using `SDL_malloc()`/`SDL_realloc()`/`SDL_strdup()` to be as cross-platform as possible to avoid having problems when porting code (as I've read that strdup isn't C standard).

Here's my code:

```
typedef struct FileList {
    char **files;
    size_t num;
} FileList;

FileList *GetFileList(const char *path){
struct dirent *dp = NULL;
DIR *dir = NULL;
size_t i = 0;
FileList *filelist = SDL_malloc(sizeof(FileList)); /* changing this to a calloc doesn't help */

/* Check if filelist == NULL */
filelist->files = NULL;

dir = opendir(path);
/* Check if dir == NULL */
while ((dp = readdir(dir))){
    if (dp->d_name[0] == '.'){
        continue;    /* skip self, parent and all files starting with . */
    }

    printf("Copying: %s\n", dp->d_name); /* Always show the name of each file */
    filelist->files = SDL_realloc(filelist->files, ++i);
    filelist->files[i-1] = SDL_strdup(dp->d_name);
    printf("Copied: %s\n\n", filelist->files[i-1]); /* Varies: either shows the file's name, either gives me plain gibberish or just nothing */
}
filelist->num = i;

closedir(dir);

return filelist;
```

}

Output varies. When it doesn't crash, I either get all filenames correctly copied, or I get most of them copied and some contain nothing or plain gibberish (as commented);  if it does crash, sometimes I get a Segfault while using `SDL_strdup()`, other times I get a Segfault when using `closedir()`.

I've even considered exchanging the `SDL_realloc()` scenario with an initial memory allocation of `filelist->files` by giving it the number of files (thanks to another function) but I get the same problem.

Any suggestion to change my coding style to a more defensive one (since I do believe this one is rather dangerous) will be appreciated, although I've tried all I could for this case. I'm currently working on a Mac OS X using built-in gcc Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.56).

Comment: You don't need to cast from `void *` to any pointer type, the cast is unecessary.

Comment: I was taught this in college as they claimed it was an old but defensive way to program. I also believed it was unnecessary, so I'll take your suggestion on it.

Comment: [It's considered bad style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: I just read that thoroughly. Never again, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need space for pointers, and `sizeof(char *) != 1` so

```
filelist->files = (char**) SDL_realloc(filelist->files, ++i);
```

needs to be

```
filelist->files = SDL_realloc(filelist->files, ++i * sizeof(char *));
```

but that's actually a bad idea, because `SDL_realloc` could return `NULL` in which case you will loose reference to the original pointer, so a good way of doing it is

```
void *ptr;

ptr = SDL_realloc(filelist->files, ++i * sizeof(char *));
if (ptr == NULL)
    handleThisErrorAndDoNotContinue();
filelist->files = ptr;
```

and always check for allocator functions if they returned `NULL`, because you have no control over the size of the data you are trying to read and you can run out of memory at least in theory, so you should make your code safe by checking the success of these functions.

Comment: Ah, I see. The size of a pointer is important when reallocating. I thought that I didn't need to specify as I was using char (1 byte), but now I understand.

Comment: `char` is always `1` byte, but you are allocating pointers, and not `char`'s.

Comment: Yes, I understood that was my mistake. I confused the two in this case, and I sincerely don't know why. I apologize for that. After some testing, I can say that it works, or I can say that I haven't gotten the same problem ever since I used your solution.